# how to make sharepoint project start with machine name instead of localhost

Tags: sharepoint

when I run my sharepoint project it starts with http://machine-name. I want it to start with http://localhost. from where can I change this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Go to sharepoint CA-> Application Management-> Configure alternate access mappings. Edit the url, change the http://machine-name to http://localhost

[image]

[image]

[image]